# Как залить файлы на сервер используя другой порт

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Имеется сервер на Linux Ubuntu.
На нем уже лежат файлы, используется по дефолту 22 порт.

Теперь появилась нужда добавить кое-что еще, но я не знаю как это сделать, чтобы порт использовался другой.

Управление провожу через ssh-коннект в консоли и FileZilla.

Comment: а в чём смысл подключаться по протоколу ssh к другому порту, если отлично работает и 22-й порт?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на сервере есть 2 проекта написанных на Django. Допустим для входа в админ панель, я использую ip адрес сервера и определенный порт. И вот по эстетическим соображениям, хотелось бы, чтобы при входе в другую админ-панельку был другой порт.

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt зачем другой порт, а не другой юзернейм?

Comment: @andreymal и вправду, что-то не подумал совсем) спасибо, на будущее буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того, чтобы программа *sshd* слушала ещё какой-нибудь порт, добавьте в её конфигурацию (обычно это файл `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`) рядом с существующей директивой

```
port 22
```

ещё одну, с каким-нибудь другим номером порта (например, `12345`):

```
port 12345
```

---

после чего программе надо дать команду перезагрузиться:

```
$ sudo service ssh reload
```